# How to prevent remove inside span using contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a editor using HTML 5 tag `contenteditable`, there i'm using `span` inside `contenteditable`, when i remove all text then span also removed but i want span should not be removed, how to prevent it?

My Code:--

```js
$('#editor').keyup(function(){
  $('#spanText').text($(this).find('span').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div contenteditable="true" id="editor"><span>This is my text</span></div>

<br><br><hr>
<div id="spanText"></div>
```

Comment: This span is part of what's editable, therefore it is deletable. Why do you want to encapsulate your text in a span in the first place?

Comment: actually there is a situation where i can't use direct content in editor so i use span as you can see in my question snippet there is issue

Comment: *then span also removed*   

you mean element span or what ? i didnt get it

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can check upon saving that the span is still there and if not, add it.

Comment: You can prevent it form being deleted since it is inside an editable element. But you can use a workaround: use Selection API and add a new `<span>` tag when all of its `Node.TEXT_NODE`  is deleted. https://javascript.info/selection-range

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. You'd be better asking how to fix the issue that made you think you need that span in the first place.

Comment: @RohitVerma I think you might use `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no straightforward way to achieve that.

You can check the text length of the element to restore the element back.

**Demo:**

```js
$('#editor').keyup(function(){
  if(!$(this).text().length){
    $(this).html('<span>&nbsp;</span>');
  }
  $('#spanText').text($(this).find('span').text().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <div contenteditable="true" id="editor"><span>This is my text</span></div>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="spanText"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the contenteditable property to the span

```
<div>
   <span contenteditable="true" id="editor">This is my text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: :) i not need to ask this bro i know i can do this but i can't do as you define

Comment: Please elaborate on what you can and can't do in your question, we don't know all your constraints.